# if (true) Shorthand

Tags: c#, operators, shorthand, shorthand-if

Is there a shorthand when checking a boolean for true?
Example:

```
if (autoConnect) Connect();
```

We can do

```
return IsOpen() ? true : false;
```

But I cant get

```
autoConnect ? Connect();
```

running. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `if(autoConnect) Connect();` is the shortest way to do this. You aren't really saving much with your proposed solution anyway.

Comment: Simple answer is: Nope.

Comment: *"I can't get this running"*  Did you post the *exact* error message you got?  Did you describe the problem? does it fail at compile-time, or fail at runtime?

Comment: Now a days disk is cheap. That three character won't save you much! So start thinking about how to write readable code. I never write if statements without braces even though it is single line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write an extension method:

```
public static void _(this bool b, Action ifTrue)
{
    if (b) { ifTrue(); }
}
```

then you could write:

```
autoConnect._(Connect);
```

although obviously this is not very readable and is not recommended.

Comment: That's one of the wierder things I've seen lately :-)

Comment: I like this! You could also have a Connect.if(autoConnect) to further confuse people :)

Comment: Also you can rename the `autoConnect` variable to `a` to save more disk space, and Connect method to `C` :p

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you can shorten is to remove the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
return IsOpen() ? true : false;
```

and just

```
return IsOpen();
```

Answer (score 2):

No, no way to get `autoConnect ? Connect();` working.

just return the bool value, don't need a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a):

```
return IsOpen();
```

Alternativelly, you return some values when a value you want to test can be null using the `??` operator, for sample:

```
 return a ?? b;
```

If `a` is null, then return `b`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, no, there is no shorthand to make

```
if (autoConnect) Connect();
```

any shorter. Also, your proposed solution only saves up 3 characters, which is an unnecessary golfing of otherwise perfectly readable code.

Answer (score 1):

As siride says `if (autoConnect) Connect();`  is the shortest way. Altough, this is just while writing code. Whenever the compiler compiles the code it will become the same as using `if (autoConnect) { Connect(); }`  or `if (autoConnect == true) { Connect(); }`.

You should use whatever you find the most clean or easiest reading.